# US Transit Visa

Tags: visas, usa, transit

I am a Indian Citizen travelling from MExico to London. Can i select a flight with a stopover in Miami? I have UK visa so does it exempt me from US transit visa?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a US transit visa (or, alternately, a visitor visa) to transit through the US. Having another country's visa does not exempt you from any US visa requirements.